# Duplicate classes when implementing the Mapbox vision sdk on andorid

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, vision

I have facing the issue of duplicate classes when adding the Mapbox Vision sdk in my project

[image]

Attached the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'

apply from: '../gradle/generate-token.gradle'
apply from: "../gradle/utils.gradle"
apply from: "../gradle/versions.gradle"
apply from: "../gradle/ktlint.gradle"

android {
namespace 'com.mapbox.vision.examples'
compileSdk 34
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.mapbox.vision.examples"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    buildTypes {

    debug{
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
        optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    //    implementation("com.serenegiant:common:2.12.4") {
    //        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    //    }

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.0"

    //    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1"

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.7.1'

    // implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android- 
    navigation:0.42.6"
    // implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android- 
    navigation-ui:0.42.6'
    implementation ("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android- 
    navigation-ui:0.42.6", {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module:'mapbox-android- 
    telemetry'
    })
    implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-core:4.0.0"


   //  ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:1.0"

   implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision:0.13.0"
   implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision- 
   ar:0.13.0"
   implementation "com.mapbox.vision:mapbox-android-vision- 
   safety:0.13.0"
   implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")

   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'

   }
```

Please share you thought's how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.